# How to create a similar to "setUp" method in unittest using pytest fixtures and django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I have the code below in my test files and trying to refactor it. I am new to pytest and i am trying to achieve the similar method setUp available with unittest to be able to retrieve the object created in the db to other function instead of repeating the codes.

In this case I want to reuse **month** from **test_setup** to the other functions.

## test_models.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestMonth:
    # def test_setup(self):
    #     month = Month.objects.create(name="january", slug="january")
    #     month.save()

    def test_month_model_save(self):
        month = Month.objects.create(name="january", slug="january")
        month.save()
        assert month.name == "january"
        assert month.name == month.slug

    def test_month_get_absolute_url(self, client):
        month = Month.objects.create(name="january", slug="january")
        month.save()
        response = client.get(reverse('core:month_detail', kwargs={'slug': month.slug}))
        assert response.status_code == 200
```

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The pytest equivalent would be like this, using a fixture:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def month(self):
    obj = Month.objects.create(name="january", slug="january")
    obj.save()
    # everything before the "yield" is like setUp
    yield obj
    # everything after the "yield" is like tearDown

def test_month_model_save(month):
    assert month.name == "january"
    assert month.name == month.slug

def test_month_get_absolute_url(month, client):
    response = client.get(reverse('core:month_detail', kwargs={'slug': month.slug}))
    assert response.status_code == 200
```