# Setting a parameter once and use it multiple times in python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and I have a design question. I have a file in this structure:

```
@pytest.fixture( scope = "module", autouse = True )
def auth( input ) :
  body = {
           name= "secret"
           type="A"
         }
.
.
.

class TestArtifacts(object):
     def test_e2e( self, input):
     name = "secret"
.
.
.

    def test_e2e_2( self, input):
     name = "secret"
.
.
.
.
```

In my code, I've set the value of the variable `name` multiple times in more than one function. I want to read the name value from a JSON file once and use it here instead of a hardcoded value. My question is how I can read and set the parameter once and then re-use the value. Where is the best place to put this parameter?

EDIT: Can defining another @pytest.fixture to read the value of the `name` variable from a JSON file and return it, be a good approach in this scenario?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a similar to "setUp" method in unittest using pytest fixtures and django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686305/how-to-create-a-similar-to-setup-method-in-unittest-using-pytest-fixtures-and)

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows two functions encapsulated in a class object. Why not use self-variables to store and use one input for both functions? It avoids the use of the globals keyword and can be easily accessed in your class functions.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, input):
        self.input = input
    def bar(self):
        print(self.input) # prints your input argument from instance initialization

    def baz(self):
        print(self.input) # prints the same argument as bar

instance1 = Foo("test")
instance1.bar()
instance1.baz()
```

Output:

```bash
test
test
```

--
(dirty fix)
If you want to reuse any of your function's parameter values (arguments), you **could** use the keyword `global` when defining variables.

The keyword `global` precedes the name of a variable whose value can be modified in a local scope (e.g., a function). It allows the local scope to access the value of your program's global variables defined outside the local scope.

Example:

```
USERNAME = None

def copy_user(user):
    global USERNAME
    USERNAME = user
```

In the code snippet above, the function `copy_user` gains access to the global variable `USERNAME` and sets its value to the parameter `user`.

Generally, the `globals` keyword is bad practice as you tend to lose track of any global variables you've modified as opposed to local variables.

Comment: The second half of your answer is great, but I'm struggling to see why you spend the first half of your answer suggesting what you know to be bad practice?

Comment: thanks for your answer, about your second-half solution, how about the fixture? auth function also needs the name variable. how I can use it in all three spots?

Comment: @Modularizer Good point! To be honest, the answer popped up in my mind right after I made a potential solution . I'll reformat my answer so the solution appears first.

Comment: @someone I believe a class variable is more suited for your situation rather than a self-variable so your "auth" function can access the variable. The "auth" function would have to be defined after the class 'TestArtifacts' since the class variable 'input' wouldn't be valid (it is called for before it is defined in the class). Instead of putting self.input, define it directly under the class scope and not in a class function.